# Why are the Volume and other indicators missing on my eMachines eM355?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, emachines

I just bought an eMachines eM355. The default installed OS is MeeGo so I installed Windows 7 into it instead. The problem, however, is that, the on-screen indicators have disappeared.

The ones I'm talking about are the small dark boxes that appear at the bottom part of the screen when you, for example, press Fn + Up Arrow (to adjust volume). The same goes for the brightness adjusting and the rest of the Fn key combinations. The keys do work but I'd still prefer to see a prompt on the screen.

Another reason why I want to solve this is because I can't effectively toggle the Bluetooth and Wifi since I don't get any prompts when pressing Fn + F3.

I wanted to include a picture of what I'm looking for but I couldn't find the exact term for such.

Comment: Found the solution http://global-download.gateway.com/GDFiles/Application/LaunchManager/LaunchManager_Dritek_4.0.18_W7x86_A.zip?acerid=634382536869909212&Step1=NETBOOK&Step2=NETBOOK&Step3=355&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=EMACHINES&SC=PA_6E

Comment: Could you post that as answer below? You will get reputation for that because people can upvote it too and you can accept it yourself. [Answering your own question is encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting the official solution that worked for me. I downloaded the needed software here:

http://global-download.gateway.com/GDFiles/Application/LaunchManager/LaunchManager_Dritek_4.0.18_W7x86_A.zip?acerid=634382536869909212&Step1=NETBOOK&Step2=NETBOOK&Step3=355&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=EMACHINES&SC=PA_6E